# The bounding box of the SVG elements is not consistent between browsers

Tags: firefox, svg, cross-browser, bounding-box

I noticed inconsistent between bounding boxes of shapes between browsers. I made SVG containing this:

```
<rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" id="rect" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" />
<path d="M100 100 L100 200 L200 200 L200 100 z" id="path" fill="red" stroke="white" stroke-width="2px"/>
```

When I trying to get their bounding boxes (element.getClientBoundingBox) on Chrome and IE the sizes are w=100, h=100 and their positions are  x=100,y=100 for both shapes.
But on FireFox for the first shape I am getting w=102,h=102 (size + borders) and x=99,y=99.
On path the values are even more strange - w=116,h=116, x=92,y=92.

Is this a Firefox bug - should be posted to Bugzilla? Do SVG specification says anything about that? (I could not find any information related to this).
Have any one know about any way of working around this problem? Especially path element is kind of unpredictable for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox includes the stroke in the bounding box. [We have asked](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Aug/0120.html) for the specification to change to reflect that this is correct.

For paths the size is too large because we don't do a very good job of working out the actual size of the stroked shape because of the complexity of estimating the size for pointy shapes. We use stroke-miterlimit to give an upper limit but it's not that great.

You could use the SVG DOM getBBox method, that excludes the shape's stroke and just gives you the fill dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for some clarification. For some moment I though that the position of this shapes are different on many browser but now I understand that the only difference are values returned by getClientBBox?

Comment: @robert-longson this is not longer the case, correct? today, getClientBoundingBox doesn't seem to include stroke

Comment: @DonBox The Firefox code has not changed in this regard, it still returns the stroke. If you've a test that proves otherwise you could raise a bug in bugzilla.

Comment: @RobertLongson has the spec changed? The "We have asked" link seems to have a nebulous response. Would be good to have both APIs, with and without strokes included, in the same coordinate system (preferably the more exact SVG coordinates, which can be transformed back to Client, or APIs for both SVG and Client coordinates). getClientBBox currently useless because not cross-platform consistent.